# calling functions in C++

Tags: c++, class, function

Im trying to call a function in C++ and I thought it would be the same as in C, but when trying to convert a C program to C++ I've run into an error where it says functions are undeclared.

Here is my class:

```
class contacts
 {
  private:;
          char *First_Name;
          char *Last_Name;
          char *home;
          char *cell;
  public:;
  //constructor
         contacts()
         {
         }  
//Function declaration     
void readfile (contacts*friends ,int* counter, int i,char buffer[],FILE*read,char user_entry3[]);

  };
```

Here is a snippit of my Menu function:

```
 if(user_entry1==1)
  {
    printf("Please enter a file name");
    scanf("%s",user_entry3); 
    read=fopen(user_entry3,"r+");

   //This is the "undeclared" function
   readfile(friends ,counter,i,buffer,read,user_entry3);
   }else;
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but every time I try and compile I get `readfile undeclared(first use this function)` What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [classes](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/)

Comment: You do not need semicolons after public and private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the "Menu" function from inside the class `contacts`? The way you have designed it, it can be only called on an instance of the the class. You have options based on exactly **what `readfile` means to `contacts`**

Im guessing the **function reads all contacts** and not just 1 contact, which means it can be made a **static function**

```
static void readfile(... ;
```

And call as

```
contacts::readfile(...;
```

Alternatively **if you dont need direct access to internals** of the class you can just declare it **outside the class** (as a free function, similar to normal C functions) and use exactly as you are doing now. This is in fact what the compiler is searching for when it comes across your code.

Also, I suggest you rename `class contacts` -> `class contact` since it appears that objects each holds the contact information of only 1 person.

Comment: would it be `static void` or `static void contact::` because when I just make it `static void` it says `char* contacts::First_Name is private`

Comment: `static void` would do if your function declaration and all its code is inside the class. If the definition (the body) is outside it would just be `void contacts::`, there is no need to repeat the static again.

Comment: does this change once you need to call a function within the main? because when i try and call the menu function within the main I get  `no matching function for call to `contacts::menu(contacts*[5],int*, int&, char[50])' `

Comment: What does the menu function look like? Is it static? If not you need to make an object of type contacts and call menu on it, like the way naveen suggested. If all of this is new to you, I suggest you read up on the basics of classes in c++, would be more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an object of `contacts` class and then call `readfile` on that object. Like this:
`contacts c; c.readfile();`.

Comment: the class seems to be 1 contact, but the function seems to be reading an entire array. it is better to make it static than call on object.

Comment: You also do not need the null else at the end of the if block.  The ending brace tells the compiler where the if block ends, and if the next token after the brace is not the 'else' keyword then the compiler treats the next token as the beginning of a new program statement.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend refactoring to use the STL vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <ReaderUtil>

using namespace std;

vector< contact > myContactCollection;
myContactCollection.push_back( Contact("Bob",....) );
myContactCollection.push_back( Contact("Jack",....) );
myContactCollection.push_back( Contact("Jill",....) );
```

Or...

```
myContactCollection = ReaderClass::csvparser(myFile);
```

where

```
ReaderClass::csvparser(std::string myFile) returns vector<Contact>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your readfile function is inside the contacts class, then the answer above is technically correct in that you need to create an instance of the object then call the function.  However, from an OO perspective, your class function should in general only operate on members of the objects of the class that contains it.  What you have here is more like a general purpose function which takes parameters of many types and only one of them is a pointer to the class that itself contains the function you are calling which if you think about it is kind of strange.  So you would be passing a pointer to the class to a member function of the class which would require two instances of it.  You cannot think of a class as a simple substitution for a pointer to a structure.  Since this is a class, you declare all the variables you need as members of the class so there is no need to pass them as parameters (one of the main points of a class is to isolate general data from class member data).  Here is an update that should point you in the right direction.

```
   class contacts
     {
      private:

          char *First_Name;
          char *Last_Name;
          char *home;
          char *cell;
          FILE *read;  // these all could also be declared as a stack variable in 'readfile'


    public:
    //constructor

    contacts()
        {
        }  

    //destruction
    ~contacts()
    {
    }

    //Function declaration     
    int contacts::readfile (char * userEnteredFilename);

    };


    contacts myContact = new contacts();

    printf("Please enter a file name");
    scanf("%s",user_entry3); 

    int iCount = myContact->readfile(user_entry3);

    // the readfile function should contain all of the file i/O code
```